# Check if DateTime expired

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5

I have a list of accounts for which I know when their passwords will expire. I want to trigger an event when the password expired so I can make an API call to get the new password.

What is the best approach to keep the track of the expiration date and raise that event.

I was thinking to have a [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) doing something like this:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (Cache is null || Cache.Accounts is null)
            return;

        _ = Task.Run(() =>
          {
              CheckForExpiredPasswords();
          }, stoppingToken);

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), stoppingToken);

    }
}

private void CheckForExpiredPasswords()
{
    foreach (var account in Cache.Accounts!)
    {
        if (account is not null && DateTime.UtcNow >= account.AccountDetails.NextPasswordChangeDateTime)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("The password for account {account} expired.", account.VaultObjectName);

            // Raise password expired event
        }
   }
}
```

Does this seems like an efficient approach?

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would scale well as he number of accounts increases. Instead, why not check for expiry at the point it's next attempted to be used and raise the event at that point? Then if no one is using the system, you don't need to look up anything.

Comment: If you are using a CancellationToken then you do not need to delay for 1 minute in a polling loop. You can find the account that is closest to expiring then delay for exactly that length of time. Once the delay has passed, you can raise an event for all accounts that have expired.

Comment: @MartinCostello This app doesn't know if/when accounts will be used, it's purpose is to get the updated passwords from an internal password store and renew the configuration of another app which is using those accounts and probably also few Azure key vaults.

Comment: @DanielDearlove I like your approach.

Comment: I would suggest the same as @MartinCostello - do the expiry check when someone attempts to use it, not proactively every 3 months when theyre never actually going to log in again

Comment: @CaiusJard This doesn't applies, the accounts are used by other applications, not by humans.

Comment: You could also use a BackgroundService that runs everyday and checks for passwords expiring in the next 24h. Raise the event for those passwords even before they have actually expired (in case this fits the business case).

Comment: Not sure what the difference is between an application and a human that uses an account? I said "someone", but substitute "something" ...

Comment: From your description, it seems that this is an Account Manage/Monitor page, you just want to get the new password from the internal password store when the password is expired(don't care how user gets the new password). If that is the case, the background service is an efficient approach. But in `CheckForExpiredPasswords` method, you could try to find the expired account using [LINQ filter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations#filtering), then using the foreach statement to loop the expired accounts and update the password.